# How to use variable of PHP anywhere in my code?

Tags: php, laravel

As I used to know, PHP loop will do from the top to the bottom. I was wondering that how can I call the variable at the bottom of the code that contain data to use at the top of the code.

Here is my sample code:

```
<tbody>
                        <?php
                            $total_asset = 0.0;
                            $total_current_asset = 0.0;
                            $total_non_current_asset = 0.0;
                            $current_debit = 0.0;
                            $current_credit = 0.0;
                        ?>
                        @if(!empty($current_assets))
                            @foreach($current_assets as $a)
                                @var $account_code = $a->code
                                @var $account_name = $a->name
                                @var $current_debit = $a->debit
                                @var $current_credit = $a->credit
                                @var $total_current_asset = $current_debit - $current_credit
                                @var $total_asset += $total_current_asset
                                @if($a->parent_id == 3 && $a->code == 111100)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $account_code .'-'. $account_name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ number_format($total_asset,2,'.',',') }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endif
                                @if($a->parent_id == 4)
                                    <tr>
                                        <?php
                                            $current_debit = $a->debit;
                                            $current_credit = $a->credit;
                                            $total_current_asset = $current_debit - $current_credit;
                                            $total_asset += $total_current_asset;
                                        ?>
                                        <td>{{ $account_code .'-'. $account_name }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ number_format($total_current_asset,2,'.',',') }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                            {{--<tr class="t-bold">--}}
                                {{--<td style="text-align:right">{{ trans('report.rpt_total') }}</td>--}}
                                {{--<td>{{ number_format($total_asset,2,'.',',') }}</td>--}}
                            {{--</tr>--}}
                        @endif
                    </tbody>
```

I am waiting for your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Uh, what? Could you clarify your question? Do you mean functions?

Comment: Just like JavaScript files, you have access to the variables globally, either by using `include 'file/with.your/variable.php';` or if it is included somewhere (like a config file that's used in this page), by using `echo $varname;` or `echo $GLOBALS['varname'];`. There are ways to do it, but in the stack somewhere it **must** be included

Comment: You can't. Like you said. PHP reads from the top to the bottom. Variables declared later in the script can't be used before they are declared.

Comment: Epodax~ Let's me explain you by my code above. I have sum up $total_asset with the last <tr>, and I want to call $total_asset to use in my first <tr>.

Comment: your laravel version ??

Answer (score 0):

Say I have a file, `config.php`, and it contains this:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_init();
$link->real_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "dbName");
?>
```

And this was found at: `/var/www/htdocs/mysite/include/config.php`

I would do this:

```
<?php
include '/var/www/htdocs/mysite/include/config.php';
var_dump($link);
?>
```

And this would grant access to this variable.

Per my comment, there are other ways to acccess such as:

```
var_dump($link); //Shown
var_dump($GLOBALS['link']); //Other way
```

But as @MagnusEriksson has said, PHP is pragmatic in the way it works, variables cannot be used before they are declared.

Also, please try to avoid your mass overuse of the `@` error suppressor, it is noise that hides things you need to develop

As well as this, you are using the `{{ ... }}` syntax for your PHP code, this is for angular JavaScript, not PHP, use the PHP tags, any of:

```
<?php //Standard
<?= //Removes the need to use echo or print keyword by having a variable such as <?=$username;?>
<? //Only if enabled on your server via php.ini
```

Comment: I don't think `@` is an error suppressor in this case. It's laravels blade-syntax. (they are all outside the PHP-tags).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, this is not something I have come across, is the same to be said for the curly syntax printing php variables?

Comment: I think that it not what I want~Sam Swift.
This is what I want:
I have sum up $total_asset with the last <tr>, and I want to call $total_asset to use in my first <tr>.

Comment: Yes. `{{ $somevar }}` echoes the variable. Laravels blade templating engine is actually quite nice

Comment: Can you look at my code, I did echo the variable, but it not working.

Comment: @TumLina, as Magnus has said, if you want to use the variable, it **must** be after it has been declared, either count first and then print and whatnot after, or ajax to a file that counts the results and returns the result for your use